# Loading ColorTransform from SharedObject

Tags: actionscript-3, air, shared-objects, colortransform, local-shared-object

I'm using a local shared object (SharedObject) to store some data for my flash game.
One of the bits of data I'd like to save is a ColorTransform object.  I have no problem saving the colorTransform to the sharedObject, but when I try to load it the game crashes.  I'm saving and loading other types of variables at the same time as the colorTransform, and they save/load just fine...  Has anyone else experienced this?  Is there a solution floating around out there?

Comment: To avoid the pain of serializing objects (converting to savable binary format); I recommend you only save the properties (channels transform) using a SharedObject than construct a new ColorTransform object at loading time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [registerClassAlias()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#registerClassAlias%28%29) like this:

```
registerClassAlias('flash.geom.ColorTransform',flash.geom.ColorTransform);
```

before loading a ColorTransform out of your SharedObject, or saving it in there. Then your loading should work like this:

```
var myCT:ColorTransform=so.data.storedCT;
```